# Transaction Module for a Banking app - Is Answered

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I need help in Transaction Class:

The transaction class with contain the following data:

A counter to track the number of transactions. Increment for every deposit or
withdrawal made. A customer is allowed to make up to 5 transactions on a single login.
o A history of the 5 possible transactions. This will be an array of dollar amounts where a
negative amount is a withdrawal and a positive number is a deposit. Clear the history
each time a customer logs in.

Transaction objects will perform the following:
o Update history to reflect any transaction made when a user is logged in. Keep track of
each transaction value made as described above in the transaction data section. After
each transaction, increment the transaction counter.
o Clear history of all amounts stored and reset the transaction count

Menu Class

```
Account[] myCustAcc = new Account[10];
Transaction myCustTrans = new Transaction();
string adminInput = "" adminName = "adm1";
int pinInput = 0, adminChoice = 0,adminPin = 9999,user = 0, input, custCount = 0;
Boolean adminQuit = false;
Boolean appQuit = false;

myCustAcc[0] = new Account();
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerFirstName("Sneha");
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerLastName("Dadhania");
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerAddress("2323 S Dobson Rd");
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerState("AZ");
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerZip(85001);
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerUserName("SMD28");
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerPin(3333);
myCustAcc[0].setCustomerBalance(87000);
custCount++;
myCustAcc[1] = new Account();
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerFirstName("Justine");
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerLastName("Timberlake");
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerAddress("TriBeca, New York. ");
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerState("NY");
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerZip(11013);
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerUserName("JTL00");
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerPin(8989);
myCustAcc[1].setCustomerBalance(34);
custCount++;

myCustAcc[2] = new Account();
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerFirstName("Guest");
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerLastName("Ghost");
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerAddress("Ghost Street");
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerState("CO");
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerZip(87655);
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerUserName("GG111");
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerPin(1111);
myCustAcc[2].setCustomerBalance(0);
custCount++;
do
{
 appQuit = false;
Console.Clear();
Console.Write("Enter UserName");
adminInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (adminInput == adminName)
{
Console.Write("Enter Admin Pin");
pinInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (pinInput != adminPin)
{
Console.WriteLine("You Have Entered Wrong Password");
Console.ReadKey();
continue; 
}
else
{
do
{
Console.Clear();
adminQuit = false;
Console.WriteLine("\t\tPlease Select from the Menu");
Console.WriteLine("\t1. Add Customer to Application");
Console.WriteLine("\t2. Return Back to Login Screen");
Console.WriteLine("\t3. Exit the Application");
adminChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
switch (adminChoice)
{
case 1:
//Add customer
break;
case 2:
adminQuit = true;
break;
case 3:
appQuit = true;
break;
default:
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Menu Selection");
return;
}} while (adminQuit == false && appQuit == false);
}}
else {
user = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < custCount; i++)
{
if (adminInput == myCustAcc[i].getCustomerUserName())
{
user = i;
break;} }
if (user == -1)
{
Console.WriteLine("User Does Not Exit !!! Please Try Again");
Console.ReadKey();
continue;
}
Console.Write("Enter User Pin");
if (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) != myCustAcc[user].getCustomerPin() )
{
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Pin");
Console.ReadKey();
continue;
}
do
{
Console.WriteLine("\t\t Welcome to Super Fast Banking Application");
Console.WriteLine("\n<<<Please Select Following Menus>>>");
Console.WriteLine("\t1> GetBalance");
Console.WriteLine("\t2> Deposit");
Console.WriteLine("\t3> Withdraw");
Console.WriteLine("\t4> Modify");
Console.WriteLine("\t5> Display");
Console.WriteLine("\t6> Exit");
input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
switch (input)
{
  case 1:
 double balance;
 balance = myCustAcc[user].getBalance();
 Console.Write("Your Current Balance is {0:C} ",balance);
 break;
 case 2:
 Console.Write("\nPlease enter Numbers to Deposit balance :");
 myCustAcc[user].Customerdeposit();
 Console.WriteLine("New Balance after Deposit is {0:C}", myCustAcc[user].getBalance());
 break;
 case 3:                           
 Console.Write("\n Please enter Dollar Amount to Withdraw:");
 myCustAcc[user].customerWithdraw();
 Console.WriteLine("New Balance after Withdraw is {0:C}",myCustAcc[user].getBalance());
  break;
  case 4:
  //modify
  break;
  case 5:
  double newDisplay;
  newDisplay = myCustAcc[user].getBalance();
  Console.WriteLine("The Balance in your Account is {0:C}",newDisplay);
  break;
  case 6:
  break;
  default: Console.WriteLine("Exit the Application!!!");
  break;
}
} while (appQuit == false);
}
Console.ReadKey();
} while (appQuit != true);
}}}
```

Some code from Account Class

```
public double getBalance()
{
return customerBalance;
 }
public void  Customerdeposit()
 {
double deposit = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
if (deposit <= 0)
 {
Console.WriteLine("\nCannot Deposit");
}
else
 {
customerBalance = customerBalance + deposit;
}
}
public void customerWithdraw()
{
double withdraw = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
{
if (withdraw >= 0)
{
customerBalance = customerBalance - withdraw;
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("There is not Sufficient fund in your account to withdraw");
} }}}
```

I try to write code for transaction class using the code below
But there are many errors at obj.Customerdeposit(amount); in both if condition and at Update(amount);

```
     class Transaction
       {
        private int[] arr;
        private int cntr;

        Transaction()
        {
            arr = new int[5];
            cntr = 0;
        }
        private void update(int amount)
        {
            arr[cntr] = amount;
            cntr++;
     }
    public void credit(Account obj, int amount)
    {
    if(cntr!=5)
    {
        obj.Customerdeposit(amount);
        return;
        Update(amount);

     }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Transaction limit exceeded");        
    }}
     public void debit(Account obj, int amount)
    {
    if(cntr!=5)
    {
    obj.customerWithdraw(amount);
    return;
    Update(-amount);
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Transaction limit exceeded");        
}    
}
}
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to track 5 transactions in a banking app

Comment: I can email you my code bcz it is difficult to paste code over here

Comment: Can you just post the logic. (Block code)

Comment: Ok I will post the logic

Comment: So... you need to write a transaction class but you don't have any idea how to start? Have you at least thought about how you could do this on paper, then try to translate that to code?

Comment: Actually, I have little idea about the transaction class, but I am not able to get user balance, deposit or withdraw

Comment: I made some changes in my code, but I am getting some errors

Comment: The error is "No overload for method 'Customerdeposit' takes 0 arguments"

Comment: Other error is "No overload for method 'customerWithdraw' takes 0 arguments"

Comment: @user3582010 You should *not* change your title to include "Answered". Instead, you should "Accept" the answer that best answers the question.

Comment: @user3582010 Yeah you can mark answers as accepted. Read http://stackoverflow.com/about (PS: You'll get a badge if you read it full)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified everything from attributes to functions, just write the code.

Now this will be spoonfeeding but then too, your changes are wrong.

Account Class:

```
public double getBalance()
{
return customerBalance;
 }
public bool Customerdeposit()
 {
double deposit = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
if (deposit <= 0)
 {
return false;
}
customerBalance = customerBalance + deposit;
return true;
}

public bool customerWithdraw()
{
double withdraw = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
{
if (withdraw <= 0 || customerBalance < withdraw )
{
return false;
}
customerBalance = customerBalance - withdraw;
return true;
}
}
 }
```

**Now your TransactionClass can be:** (add other functionalities yourself)

```
class Transaction
{
private int[] arr;
private int cntr;
    Transaction()
{
    arr = new int[5];
    cntr = 0;
}

    private void update(int amount)
{
    arr[cntr]=amount;
    cntr++;
}

    public void credit(Account obj, int amount)
{
    if(cntr!=5)
    {
        if(obj.CustomerDeposit(amount))
        Update(amount);   //works only when true returned from above.
        else
        //print message 


    }
    else
    Console.WriteLine("Transaction limit exceeded");        
}

    public void debit(Account obj, int amount)
{
    if(cntr!=5)
    {
        if(obj.CustomerWithdraw(amount))
        Update(-amount);
        else
        //print any message 

    }
    else
    Console.WriteLine("Transaction limit exceeded");        
}

}
```

Call will be made for each transaction:

```
Transaction trans= new Transaction();
trans.credit(myCustAcc[user],500);
```

Comment: I updated some of code for deposit and withdraw method and in switch case where they are called

Comment: But i am some problems over there, like if the customer has $0 balance, it should not allow them to withdraw, but my is allowing to withdraw

Comment: We are not using try and catch in our programming. I know we can write if-else statement instead of try and catch. but i am not sure to write your code in if-else statements. can you help me do that

Comment: I updated the code with if else code with the code for Transaction class

Comment: You've put up wrong code (Used return statements wrongly) Just try to understand the code and do dry run on paper.